# List the files of another format while finding a certain name pattern

Tags: shell, command-line, find, wildcards

I had wanted to edit the txt files of `videoA` and `videoB` only if the movs files names contains the namespace -`test`

For eg.

```
videoDir
    |-videoA
        |- videoA_v001_test.mov
        |- videoA_v001_info.txt
    |-videoB
        |- videoB_v001_test.mov
        |- videoB_v001_info.txt
    |-videoC
        |- videoC_v002.mov
        |- videoC_v002_info.txt
```

Above, I want to edit `videoDir/videoA/videoA_v001_info.txt` and `videoDir/videoB/videoB_v001_info.txt` but not `videoC_v002_info.txt` since the corresponding `.mov` file name doesn't contain `test`.

I come up with the command - `find -name "*.mov" | grep -rn "test" | find -name "*.txt"`, `find -name "*.mov" | grep -rn "test" does indeed lists out the 2 files that fulfills the condition (videoA and videoB). I added in`find -name "*.txt"` as I had thought it will filter it down to the txt files within the output results, however I was wrong as it is still listing all the txt files

Comment: There is no `test` in your example command. `grep -r` doesn't make sense if `grep` operates on files. `grep` doesn't read its search files from `stdin`. I have no idea what the `find` call is supposed to do.

Comment: There is a typo in my code. What I really wanted to achieve is to edit `.txt` files only if the mov files within their directories contains `test` in the file naming.

Comment: ... so why not just `find -name '*test*.mov'`?

Comment: @steeldriver I am using the `mov` file naming as one of the condition to narrow my search. So if that condition is fulfilled, I will then need to locate the .txt file within and edit that txt file.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
vi ./**/*_test.mov(.s:_test.mov:_info.txt:)
```

Comment: I keep getting `Badly placed ()'s.`

Comment: @dissidia as I said, that's zsh syntax. So you need to enter that at the prompt of that shell.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
find . -name "*.mov" -exec grep test {} + | sed -n 's/^\([^:]*\):.*$/\1/p' | xargs -d \\n -n 1 $EDITOR
```

for opening one file at a time

or

```
find . -name "*.mov" -exec grep test {} + | sed -n 's/^\([^:]*\):.*$/\1/p' | xargs -d \\n $EDITOR
```

for opening them simultaneously

(assuming the file names do not contain a colon)

Comment: It doesn't seems to work? But even so why is it `grep mov`?